# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am building the docker image of my project using the Dockerfile provided with it but docker container is always remains in restarting state. Below is the container log which I see:-
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
Can some one prove me with the possible solution to it and also tell what's the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this issue was because I had Windows-style line endings on my docker file script for Linux.

I fixed this by running [dos2unix](https://chocolatey.org/packages/dos2unix) on the file so that it now had Unix-style line endings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give a lot of information but:
I had a similiar error before that happened because some files copied (added or as volume) to the container had windows line endings instead of linux line endings... To fix it I used the program dos2unix to change the line endings of the file. Maybe this can help you. (also check this: https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-175-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file/20025/2)

Comment: what additional information do you need

Comment: your dockerfile and docker-compose.yml would probably be a good starting point