# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" on Alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to follow the instructions on slimming my Docker files by using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). In particular, I try to copy over the built executable from the builder image into `alpine:latest` with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim AS builder

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends fp-compiler fp-units-fcl fp-units-net libc6-dev

COPY src /whatwg/wattsi/src
RUN /whatwg/wattsi/src/build.sh

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=builder /whatwg/wattsi/bin /whatwg/wattsi/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["/whatwg/wattsi/bin/wattsi"]
```

However, when I try to run the resulting docker image using `docker run`, I get the error

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

What is going on, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has come up multiple times, and this error seems to have many possible causes. Some are [missing or wrong shebang instructions in any bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61331059/3191), or [Windows line endings in files copied to the volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331320/3191). However, in my case, it for a different reason.

This error occurred because the built binary (`/whatwg/wattsi/bin` in the question) depends on the system having [glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372872/what-is-the-role-of-libcglibc-in-our-linux-app) installed. Presumably, when running, something is looking for the system's glibc, but Alpine Linux does not have glibc available. (Instead, it uses musl-libc, which is more minimal, but less popular.)

The easiest fix for this is to use a different base image that has glibc available. You could use the `debian:stable-slim` that you're using in the builder image (69.2 MiB), but a smaller one would be Google's [Distroless base image](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/base/README.md) `gcr.io/distroless/base` (16.9 MiB). This is still larger than `alpine:latest` (5.61 MiB) or the Distroless static image (1.82 MiB), but it's not bad.

There are probably other solutions, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37818831/3191) discusses ways to set up glibc on Alpine Linux. Or, you could figure out how to change your compiler/linker to link against the system libc (i.e., musl-libc on Alpine Linux), instead of assuming the existence of glibc specifically. But for my case, `gcr.io/distroless/base` worked perfectly.

Comment: One important correction: Alpine doesn't have *glibc* (GNU libc) installed - it does have a libc. libc provides the standard C library and the POSIX API and therefore is builtin to any Linux distro. glibc is the defacto standard libc implementation. Alpine Linux builds on the musl-libc library, which is a minimal and strict POSIX libc implementation, and is indeed not compatible with glibc.

Comment: Thank you @valiano. I've updated the answer to be more along those lines.